# Swift: The best way to show and hide different views based off of my UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to show one view when the segmented control highlights the first option. When the user highlights the other option, I want the first view to disappear (or hide) and the other view to become visible. Then, if the user presses the first option again, the second view hides and the first becomes visible.

What is the best way to do this?

I do not want to switch ViewControllers, but simply Views who are both using the same ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that would be to give a `tag` to each `view` (as in your `segment`'s indices) and call a method when the its value is changed that would hide all `view`'s accept the one with the right `tag` number.

Comment: What's the Swift method to do that?

Comment: You can create an IBAction and connect it to `valueChanged` and name it anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook the `UISegmentedControl` from the view controller to the code using an `@IBAction` and use the following method:

```
@IBAction func switchView(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    // Change your view controller's view property
    // to reference whatever custom views you have.   
    if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

        self.view = viewOne
    } else {
        self.view = viewTwo
    }
}
```

viewOne and viewTwo being `UIViews`